# Printing Array in struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, printf

I have a struct in my program

```
struct data
{
double a;
double b;
}x[ ]={0.1 , 0.1,
0.2 , 0.1,
0.3 , 0.1,
0.4 ,0.2,
0.5 , 0.3,
0.6 , 0.4,
0.1 , 0.4,
0.7 , 0.4,
0.8 , 0.8,
0.6 , 0.6, 
0.6 , 0.6, 
0.6 , 0.6};
```

The array has 12 members as shown. After some computation I want to display the members one by one. How can I accomplish it.

Right now I am doing this way.

```
for (i=0;i<12;i++)
{
printf("\t index %x value %x  \n\r",i, x[i]);
}
```

But I get strange results. How can I solve the problem.

Comment: Even it doesn't solve your problem, when compiling with a compiler which supports `printf` format check it wouldn't let you conpile it and the compiler hint could have had help you to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't print the two values by using `x[i]`. You must print them one-by-one.

You probably want something like:

```
for (i=0;i<12;i++)
{
    printf("\t index %d value %f, %f  \n\r",i, x[i].a, x[i].b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `x[i]` is a variable of type `struct data`, and there's no format specifier to print that *directly*. You need to refer to the exact member variables (`x[i].a`, `x[i].b`) and print them individually.

That said, as you've shown your code, `%x` expects an argument of type `unsigned int` and you cannot pass a`double` variable there. It's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1/p8

> `o,u,x,X` 
>  **The `unsigned int` argument** is converted to unsigned octal (`o`), unsigned
>   decimal (`u`), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (`x` or `X`) in the style *dddd;* [...]

Use `%f` to print `double` values, in general.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks for bringing that into notice, fixed. :)